# Possible XSS detected with . on echo

Tags: php

I'm currently cleaning up my code with PHPCS Security Audit, on one of the lines it says "Possible XSS detected with . on echo" I've spent the last 3 hours on Google and reading through the PHP manual trying to figure this out without any solution, if anyone could help me I'd really appreciate it, thank you.

The line that's causing the error is the echo line

```
try {
$this->conn = new \PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->db_host . ";dbname=" . $this->db_name, $this->username, $this->password);
} catch (PDOException $exception) {
echo "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage();
}
```

Please note, the code works without any problem, it's just if there's a better way to output the echo line I'd like to learn from it, thank you.

Comment: I think the key word here is `Possible` meaning `take a look at it just in case`. I don't really see how you could get a XSS from echoing a PDO exception error. I would probably just send that error to a log file, there really is no need for the end user to see that you have a database connection error. You can output static HTML telling the user an error occurred and in the background save the error to a file out of the document root.

Comment: @Rasclatt thank you for clearing that up, I really appreciate it.